# Draw a line in a 3D set of images

Tags: matlab, plot, dicom

In other words the same line should appear atop each image. Im using the `imshow3D` function to preview my images.

Comment: so did you try my suggestion?

Comment: sorry or the super late reply. i phrased my question incorrectly. I was hoping to pick two points in my code and have a line go from one to the other and have that on top of every image. Im able to do it where the goes through every image but the line appears as a dot on each image

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it without `imshow3D` (just create a new .m file with the function below). I think it will be easier for you to understand what is going on behind the code then.

The trick is to add a pushbutton and the function [imline](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imline.html) in the callback in order to *interactively* draw a line. Then, as the user scrolls through the stack we use the function `line` to actually draw a line using the position of the previously drawn line.

I used the `mri` data that ships with Matlab but that should work with your data/dicom images/whatever.

Code:

```
function ScrollMRI(~)
clc
clear
close all

%// Load demo data
S = load('mri');

%// Get dimensions and number of slices.
ImageHeight = S.siz(1); %// Not used here
ImageWidth = S.siz(2); %// Not used here
NumSlices = S.siz(3);

S.D = squeeze(S.D);

%// Create GUI
hFig = figure('Position',[100 100 400 400],'Units','normalized');

%// create axes with handle
handles.axes1 = axes('Position', [0.2 0.2 0.6 0.6]);

%// create y slider with handle
handles.y_slider = uicontrol('style', 'Slider', 'Min', 1, 'Max', NumSlices, 'Value',1, 'Units','normalized','position', [0.08 0.2 0.08 0.6], 'callback', @(s,e) UpdateY);
handles.SlideryListener = addlistener(handles.y_slider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) YListenerCallBack);

%// Create pusbutton to draw line
handles.DrawLineButton= uicontrol('style', 'push','position', [40 40 100 30],'String','Draw line', 'callback', @(s,e) DrawLine);

%// Flag to know whether pushbutton has been pushed
handles.LineDrawn = false;

%// Show 1st slice
imshow(S.D(:,:,1))

guidata(hFig,handles);

%// Listeners callbacks followed by sliders callbacks. Used to display each
%// slice smoothly.
    function YListenerCallBack

        handles = guidata(hFig);

        %// Get current slice
        CurrentSlice = round(get(handles.y_slider,'value'));

        hold on
        imshow(S.D(:,:,CurrentSlice));

        %// If button was button, draw line
        if handles.LineDrawn
            line([handles.LinePos(1,1) handles.LinePos(2,1)],[handles.LinePos(1,2) handles.LinePos(2,2)],'LineWidth',2,'Color','y');
        end
        drawnow

        guidata(hFig,handles);

    end

    function UpdateY(~)

        handles = guidata(hFig); %// Get handles.
        CurrentSlice = round(get(handles.y_slider,'value'));

        hold on
        imshow(S.D(:,:,CurrentSlice));

        if handles.LineDrawn
            line([handles.LinePos(1,1) handles.LinePos(2,1)],[handles.LinePos(1,2) handles.LinePos(2,2)],'LineWidth',2,'Color','y');
        end
        drawnow

        guidata(hFig,handles);

    end

%// Pushbutton callback to draw line.
    function DrawLine(~)
        handles = guidata(hFig); %// Get handles.

        hLine = imline(gca);

        %// Get position of line and store it in handles structure.
        handles.LinePos = hLine.getPosition(); %// handles.LinePos is a 2-by-2 array [X1 Y1; X2 Y2]

        %// Set tag to true.
        handles.LineDrawn = true;
        guidata(hFig,handles);
    end

end
```

Here is a screenshot of the GUI before pressing the button:

[image]

and then after pressing it and drawing a line:

[image]

The line stays at the same position as you scroll through the stack.

Hope that helps get you started!